# Is my instruction format for this processor correct?

Tags: architecture, logic, cpu, processor

I'm supposed to create an instruction format fo a processor with the given details.

With my previous question, I learned better how to find out the bit size of the following details (thanks! to https://stackoverflow.com/users/655436/fukanchik). It's done by log_2(x).

Using this, the following details have the sizes in bits:

```
32 instructions - 5 bits
2 address-machine
word size 32 bit - 32 bits
16 registers - 4 bits
64 Mwords central memory available - 96 bits
memory is byte-addressable - 1 bit
constant are of 1 word-wide
addressings: directly register, indirectly register, directly storing, immediate - 3 bits
register indicated with 16 bit index - 16 bits
```

Now, using this information, I need to create the instruction format.

It includes Opcode (5 bits), 1st operator (direct register, so 4 bits), adressings (3 bits), direction (1 bit), 2nd operator (indirect register, so 4 bits).

In total I got 17 Bits (5+4+3+1+4), is this really right? I shouldn't get 32 Bits actually?

Well this was the first word.

The second word: It's the constant or index, so 16 bits.

The third word, really no idea, does it even exist?

I'd be very glad if someone could help me, or give me hints / tell me my mistakes. I spent lots of hours on this and didn't really come far, very sad and I haven't got the opportunity to learn it well...